# firebase.database is not a function despite importing all from firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wrote a simple program with the angular framework to read values from a database, but when I ng serve the console gives the error 
'firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.database is not a function'

Here is the component in its entirety:

```
import {NgModule,Component} from '@angular/core'
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
import {firebaseConfig} from './firebaseConfig' // I put the credentials of my 
                                            // database in this file

@NgModule ({})
@Component({
    selector: 'practiceFb',
    template:``
})
export class practiceFb {

constructor () {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    var TheItem= firebase.database().ref('TheItem');
    TheItem.on("value", (snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
    })
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are importing from `firebase/app` rather than just `firebase`.

Try changing

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

to

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. If you deem this to be a sufficient answer, please mark the answer as successful using the checkmark on the left of the answer.